# $\lim_{x\to 1/2} \left(\frac{\tan(\pi x)}{2x-1}+\frac{2}{\pi(2x-1)^2}\right)$ using L' Hopital

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

My task is to find
$$\lim_{x\to 1/2}  \left(\frac{\tan(\pi x)}{2x-1}+\frac{2}{\pi(2x-1)^2}\right)$$
using L' Hopital, so I first wrote it in a way that the numerator and denominator have the limit $0$ at $x=1/2$:
$$\lim_{x\to 1/2}\frac{\pi (2x-1)^2\tan(\pi x)+4x-2}{\pi(2x-1)^3}$$
But when I calculate the derivative I still get a $0$ in the denominator, while the numerator doesnt seem to be $0$.

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: You have to derivative until it comes out of 0/0. You can write `tan(πx)` as `πx` then try to limit ! Both numerator and denominator will become x3 . Then derivative.

Comment: the denominator can be $(2x-1)^2$,so you only need two times.

Comment: May be, you could make life easier setting first $x=y+\frac 12$ and simplifying the expression.

Comment: Why use L'Hopital? Teacher's sadism?

Comment: You cannot apply the L'Hospital rule as after simplification it comes out of 0/0 . So the answer could be infinity .

Comment: @Yogus according wolfram alpha its pi/6, not sure why

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici and then taking lim_y->0?

Comment: Yes, for sure (trivial trick). Don't forget to simplify the tangent.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28y-%3E0%29+%28%28tan%28pi%28y%2B1%2F2%29%29%29%2F%282+%28y%2B1%2F2%29-1%29%2B2%2Fpi%282+%28y%2B1%2F2%29-1%29%5E2%29 != http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_x-%3E1%2F2+%28tan%28pi+x%29%2F%282x-1%29%2B2%2F%28pi%282x-1%29%5E2%29%29 doesnt seem to work or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls Are you sure the answer is pi/6 ? My answer comes to infinity ! Can you link me to the original question wolfram

Comment: @Yogus http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_x-%3E1%2F2+%28tan%28pi+x%29%2F%282x-1%29%2B2%2F%28pi%282x-1%29%5E2%29%29

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls. What did I say ? Replace and simplify everything first. The limit exists. Keep the expression as you wrote but simplify !

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls Did you find the solution ? I am still stick to my answer ~ `infinity` .

Comment: @Yogus will get solution in university next week and post it then here, I wrote pi/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using first the idea of Claude Leibovici, let be $x=t/\pi+1/2$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 1/2}\frac{\pi (2x-1)^2\tan(\pi x)+4x-2}{\pi(2x-1)^3} =
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi(1-t\cot t)}{2t^2}.
$$
And *before* using L'Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi(1-t\cot t)}{2t^2} = 
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi(\tan t-t)}{2t^2\tan t} =
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi(\tan t-t)}{2t^3}
$$
by the equivalence $\tan t\sim t$ when $t\to 0$.
Now, you can easily use L'Hôpital and again the equivalence:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi(\tan t-t)}{2t^3} =
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\pi\tan^2 t}{6t} = \frac\pi6
$$